# glShaderSource crashes

Tags: c++, opengl

I use:

```
std::string source;
char value;
std::ifstream stream(paths[id]);
while (stream.get(value)) {

    source += value;
}
stream.close()

        
        
int shader = glCreateShader(mode);
shaders[id] = shader;


glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const GLchar* const *)source.c_str(), nullptr);

glCompileShader(shader);
```

And the app crashes on
Also source varible contains exactly:

```
 #version 330 core
 layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

And the app just crashes!

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here: `(const GLchar* const *)source.c_str()`. The fact that it didn't work without a cast (effectively a `reinterpret_cast`) is a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Save the pointer to a variable: `const char *ptr = source.c_str();`, then pass `&ptr` to `glShaderSource`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this

```
glShaderSource(shader, 1, (const GLchar* const *)source.c_str(), nullptr);
```

try to do this

```
const char* src = source.c_str();
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src,nullptr);
```